# MVC areas not diplaying when registering routes and areas with MVC extensions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am using [MVC Extension with Autofac](http://mvcextensions.github.com/) and I am having issues with my areas.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Initially I had the following in my `global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : AutofacMvcApplication
{
     public MvcApplication()
     {
          Bootstrapper.BootstrapperTasks
               .Include<RegisterControllers>();
     }
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

     RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

     base.OnStart();
}

public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
     filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

     routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
     );
}
```

With this code my areas displayed well.  `http://localhost:19857/Administration` displays my Index view.

If I want MVC Extensions to register my routes and areas for me then `http://localhost:19857/Administration` displays nothing, just a 404 error.

This is the updated `global.asax.cs` to register my routes and areas:

```
public class MvcApplication : AutofacMvcApplication
{
     public MvcApplication()
     {
          Bootstrapper.BootstrapperTasks
               .Include<RegisterAreas>()
               .Include<RegisterControllers>()
               .Include<RegisterRoutesBootstrapperTask>();
     }

     protected override void OnStart()
     {
          RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

          base.OnStart();
     }

     public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
     {
          filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
     }
}
```

My `RegisterRoutesBootstrapperTask class`:

```
public class RegisterRoutesBootstrapperTask : RegisterRoutesBase
{
     public RegisterRoutesBootstrapperTask(RouteCollection routes)
          : base(routes)
     {
     }

     protected override void Register()
     {
          Routes.Clear();

          Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

          Routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
          );
     }
}
```

Why won't my areas display?

**UPDATE**

When I go to `http://localhost:19857/Administration` then defaults to the Dashboard controllers Index view.  Here is my area's registration code:

```
public override string AreaName
{
     get
     {
          return "Administration";
     }
}

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
     context.MapRoute(
          "Administration_default",
          "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
}
```

Comment: What if you visit `http://localhost:19857/Administration/Home/Index` (or the action in your default area controller)?

Comment: Please see my update.  The above URL uses the Dashboard controller's Index view which is in the Administration structure.

Comment: Yeah, but can you vist `http://localhost:19857/Administration/dashboard/index/` or do you get 404 then too?

Comment: Yes `http://localhost:19857/Administration/Dashboard/Index` also gives the 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have sorted out the problem.  The problem is with the `Routes.Clear();`  I took it out and now everything is working fine.  Here is my changes that I did to the code above:

```
public class RegisterRoutesBootstrapperTask : RegisterRoutesBase
{
     public RegisterRoutesBootstrapperTask(RouteCollection routes)
          : base(routes)
     {
     }

     protected override void Register()
     {
          Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

          Routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
     }
}
```

Here is my updated `global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : AutofacMvcApplication
{
     public MvcApplication()
     {
          Bootstrapper.BootstrapperTasks
               .Include<RegisterAreas>()
               .Include<RegisterControllers>()
               .Include<RegisterRoutesBootstrapperTask>()
               .Include<AutoMapperBootstrapperTask>();
     }
}
```